# Extjs 4 Loading a view from controller 2

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs4

Continuing the question here: [Extjs 4 MVC loading a view from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890272/extjs-4-mvc-loading-a-view-from-controller) how do you load the created view into your viewport?

Here is what I did:

```
this.getViewportContent().insert(Ext.widget('templatecategorycreate'));
```

where getViewportContent() returns where I wanted to add that view to, but it does not work. Error was:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method
>   'substring' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer is as simple as:

> this.getViewportContent().add(Ext.widget('templatecategorycreate'));

Can't believe I had to debug the whole extjs trace to get into this...

Comment: And it allways had been... The method to add components to an existing component is add, where did you get insert from?