# how to call an addRow view method from an ExtJS4 controller

Tags: extjs

I have a controller and a view and want to push a line from a controller when item is selected. 
Where it says  onItemSelect: that's where I need to make a call, and don't know how...
Thank you.

controller is this:

```
Ext.define('Application.controller.ItemController', {
// Extend basic controller object
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
// Attach store classes to this controller
stores: ['Items'],
// Attach model classes to this controller
models: ['Item'],
// ..and last but not least - the view classes
views: ['item.List', 'item.Show'],
// Refs parameter defines references to certain
// instances of components pointed by selector
refs: [
    {
        // Ref determines the name of the automagic
        // this.get[ref-goes-here] method that returns
        // instance of certain component
        ref : 'itemShowDesc',
        // Select #item-description component in
        // item.Show view
        selector: 'itemShow > #item-description'
    }
],
// when including the controllers in your application, 
// the framework will automatically load the controller 
// and call the init method on it
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'itemList' : {
            // Action to be performed on select
            select: this.onItemSelect
        }
    });
},
onItemSelect: function (selModel, selection) {
    // Executed only when selection is a leaf
    (selection.data.leaf) ? this.getItemShowDesc().addRow(selection.raw.description,'','','','','','') : null;
}
```

});

and the view is this:

```
Ext.define('Application.view.item.Show', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias : 'widget.itemShow',
requires: [
    'Ext.selection.CellModel',
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.util.*',
    'Ext.form.*',
    'Application.model.Item'
],
xtype: 'cell-editing',

title: 'Favorite Books',
frame: true,

initComponent: function() {
    this.cellEditing = new Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing({
        clicksToEdit: 1
    });

    Ext.apply(this, {
        width: 680,
        height: 350,
        plugins: [this.cellEditing],
        store: new Ext.data.Store({
            // destroy the store if the grid is destroyed
            autoDestroy: true,
            model: Application.model.Item,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                // load remote data using HTTP
                url: 'resources/data/grid/books.xml',
                // specify a XmlReader (coincides with the XML format of the returned data)
                reader: {
                    type: 'xml',
                    // records will have a 'plant' tag
                    record: 'book'

                }
            },
            sorters: [{
                property: 'common',
                direction:'ASC'
            }]
        }),
        columns: [{
            header: 'Book Id',
            dataIndex: 'item_id',
            width: 100

        }, {
            header: 'Author',
            dataIndex: 'author',
            width: 100
        },  {
            header: 'Title',
            dataIndex: 'title',
            width: 250
        },{
            header: 'Description',
            dataIndex: 'description',
            width: 495
        },{
            header: 'Price',
            dataIndex: 'price',
            width: 70,
            align: 'right',
            renderer: 'usMoney'               
        },{
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            width: 30,
            sortable: false,
            menuDisabled: true,
            items: [{
                icon: 'resources/images/icons/delete.gif',
                tooltip: 'Delete Plant',
                scope: this,
                handler: this.onRemoveClick
            }]
        }],
        selModel: {
            selType: 'cellmodel'
        }

    });

    this.callParent();

    this.on('afterlayout', this.loadStore, this, {
        delay: 1,
        single: true
    })
},
addRow: function(inItemID,inDisplay,inSex,inAuthor,inTitle,inDescription,inPrice){
     // Create a record instance through the ModelManager
    var r = Ext.ModelManager.create({
        item_id: inItemID,
        display: inDisplay,
        sex: inSex,
        author: inAuthor,
        title: inTitle,
        description: inDescription,
        price: inPrice
    }, 'Item');
    store.insert(0, r);
    cellEditing.startEditByPosition({row: 0, column: 0});
}
, 

loadStore: function() {
    this.getStore().load({
        // store loading is asynchronous, use a load listener or callback to handle results
        callback: this.onStoreLoad
    });
},

onStoreLoad: function(){
    Ext.Msg.show({
        title: 'Store Load Callback',
        msg: 'Favorites were loaded, data available for processing',
        icon: Ext.Msg.INFO,
        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
    });
},


onRemoveClick: function(grid, rowIndex){
    this.getStore().removeAt(rowIndex);
}
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ref for `itemShowDesc` is selecting a child component of `itemShow`. So when you do `this.getItemShowDesc().addRow()`, you're calling a method on whatever **`#item-description`** is, not on the `Application.view.item.Show` class.

Comment: I've tried this.getItemShowAddRow() and this.getItemShowaddRow and none of them exist. in fact I looked at the model, and I cannot find my addrow function anywhere...  Thanks for taking the time really appreciate it.

Comment: Try adding a ref for itemShow. Then call this.getItemShow().addRow(). The ItemShow class is where you have defined the method, so you'll need the reference to this class in order to call the method.

Comment: I've changed the refs to  " ref : 'itemShow',
selector:'Application.view.item.Show' " but the grid object is empty when called this.getItemShow(), there is another method this.getItemShowView() which seems right but doesn't have my addRow() method, any ideas?

Comment: After much search I figured it out, turns out I had to use a css selector in the refs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890272/extjs-4-mvc-loading-a-view-from-controller