# Extjs 4 MVC Declare a variable to use in a whole controller

Tags: extjs, model-view-controller, extjs4

In my controller I want to use certain variables in several places.

For example I got a form with few fields (combo / textfield) and I want to use a link to them in a various places of my controller code. How can / should I declare such variable?
Usually I use:

```
refs: [
    {
        ref: 'myCombo',
        selector: 'myPanel combo[name=myCombo]'
    },
    {
        ref: 'myTextfield',
        selector: 'myPanel textfield[name=myTextfield]'
    }
]
```

But is it ok to use getMyCombo() / getMyTextfield() every time I have to work with this fields in my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "refs" feature of the controller is really just generating getter functions for you by using `Ext.ComponentQuery` with the provided CSS `selector`. The way you're using them is one way you can make use of the system, though you can also use `refs` to instantiate (for example) views for the controller using their configured `alias` or `xtype`. In your example, you're saving yourself the hassle of re-writing some long-ish `ComponentQuery` calls.

The 'autoCreate' option, although not documented, is great for this type of thing if for example you wanted to always instantiate a new instance of a certain object every time the controller is activated, you could do so in the init() function.

[The answer posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8734556/1021046) demonstrates using `refs` to create new instances and further explains the functionality of `autoCreate` and `forceCreate` options.

If you want to use an object or some variable throughout your controller, just set a property on the controller, most suitably in the `init` method...

```
Ext.define('App.controller.Messaging', {
    /** Include models, stores, views, etc... */
    refs: [{
        ref: 'messageBox', // creates magic method "getMessageBox"
        xtype: 'my-messagebox', // in the class file: alias: 'widget.my-messagebox'
        selector: '', // could be itemId, name, etc. Same rules as a CSS selector
        autoCreate: true // automatically create when "getMessageBox()" is called
    }],

    /** I always initialize controllers as-needed, passing the application object */
    init: function(app){
        var me = this;

        // Initialize whatever you need, maybe set up some controller properties
        this.eventBus = app.getEventBus();
        this.user     = app.getActiveUser();

        // I prevent listeners from being established twice like this..
        if(this.inited === true)
            return;

        this.inited = true; // nothing past this line will be executed twice

        // Observe view events
        this.control();

        // Listen for application events
        app.on({
           'getMessages': {fn: me.showMessageBox, scope: me}
        });

        // Specific controller events
        this.on({
            'someEvent': {fn: me.someFunction, scope: me}
        });

    },

    // A function using controller properties defined in the init() method
    someFunction = function(){
        var me = this; // controller

        // Lets show the active user
        console.warn("Active User", me.user);

        // And then fire an event, passing this controller
        me.eventBus.fireEvent('somethingHappened', me); 
    },

    // Invoked on the application event "getMessages"
    showMessageBox: function(sessionId){
        var me = this; // controller

        /** ... Load the messages for the provided sessionId ... */

        // Then create an instance of the message box widget as property on the controller
        me.messageBox = me.getMessageBox({ 
             /** pass config to the view here if needed */
        });
    }
});
```